# Blender donut sprinkles appearing in donut

Tags: blender

So i was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA) tutorial, and I made a donut.[donut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wBdQ.png)

For some reason, when i select the icing (in a separate mesh than the donut) and use particles, hair, and change the "render as" to an object, and select the object as a sprinkle that i made, it creates lots of sprinkles *INSIDE* the icing. how do i move the sprinkles up to the top of the icing?

[the donut.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Qj-pLSErfloA5zmZthykRA6TO7tUJQj/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks!

Comment: please answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and the way I fixed it was, by applying the solidify modifier. Try it, might work for you.

Thanks,

Comment: I think it should be rather a comment than an answer.